# Lorentz contraction from the book by Electrodynamics by Griffiths

Tags: special-relativity

In the book Electrodynamics by Griffiths, derivation of Lorentz contraction is done by taking a round trip of light in a moving train. [image]

My question is: Why don't I get the expected result by taking only one way journey of light i.e. from back end to front end of the train.
[image]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misapplying the time dilation formula, $\Delta \overline t =\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}\ \Delta t$.

$\Delta \overline t$ is the proper time, that is the time between two events as measured in a frame of reference in which the events occur at the same place. $\Delta t$ is an improper time, the time between the same two events as measured in a frame (moving with velocity ±$v$ wrt the other frame) in which the events occur in different places.

In your one-way light transit thought experiment, the emission and arrival of the light do not occur at the same place – even in your railway carriage!